# How to set up Next.js render in Express routing?

Tags: node.js, express, routes, next.js

`app.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 3000;
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';

const app = next({ dev });
const handle = app.getRequestHandler();

app
  .prepare()
  .then(() => {
    const server = express();

    const indexRouter = require('./routes/indexRouter');

    server.use(indexRouter);
    server.all('*', (req, res) => {
      return handle(req, res);
    });

    server.listen(port, (err) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:' + port);
    });
  })
  .catch((ex) => {
    console.error(ex.stack);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

`indexRoutes.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/user');

router.post('/api/signup', userController.signup);
```

I want to render the component via Next.js in `indexRoutes.js`. I've seen others do in the main `app.js`.

```
server.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  app.render(req, res, '/login');
});
```

But I don't understand how I can do it in a separate file. I tried to do this, but no result.

`indexRoutes.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const next = require('next');
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const app = next({ dev });
const router = express.Router();
const userController = require('../controllers/user');

router.post('/api/signup', userController.signup);
router.get('/login', (req, res) => {
  return app.render(req, res, '/login'); // this does not work
});
```

How can I solve my problem?

Comment: @juliomalves no errors, but url /login loads endlessly.

Comment: @Лукас have you exported the controller method? From your provided code I understand you've created signup controller.

Comment: @FahimHoque The controller is fine. I have a problem with routing / login, unable to render a React component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put the routes in a separate file you can create the following `indexRouter.js` file:

```js
// routes/indexRouter.js

const userController = require('../controllers/user');

const indexRouter = (server, app) => {
    server.post('/api/signup', userController.signup);
    server.get('/login', (req, res) => {
        return app.render(req, res, '/login');
    });
};

module.exports = indexRouter;
```

You can then require it from `app.js` and pass the `server` and `app` objects to it.

```js
// app.js

// ...

app
    .prepare()
    .then(() => {
        const server = express();

        const indexRouter = require('./routes/indexRouter');

        indexRouter(server, app)
        
        server.all('*', (req, res) => {
            return handle(req, res);
        });

        server.listen(port, (err) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            console.log('> Ready on http://localhost:' + port);
        });
    })
    .catch((ex) => {
        console.error(ex.stack);
        process.exit(1);
    });
```